# что использовать вместо textview для вывода большого объема текста из БД

Tags: android, webview, textview

что использовать вместо textview для вывода большого объема текста из БД.  при использоване textview приложения тормозит.  webview нормально показывает но структура текста пропадает webview показывает без пробелов и отступов

Comment: поискал в интернете - не нашел , как ни странно, готовой либы. Решил заморочиться, и сделать. Как сделаю - выложу

Comment: Можно порезать текст на логические части и выводит списком через RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

Только что доделал библиотеку, загрузил на [Github](https://github.com/metalurgus/LongTextView), [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/#metalurgus/LongTextView/1.0):

Добавить репозиторий в `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Добавить `dependency` в `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.metalurgus:LongTextView:1.0'
}
```

В `XML` использовать так:

```
<com.metalurgus.longtextview.LongTextView 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:gravity="left|top"
        app:maxLinesPerItem="2"
        app:text="@string/long_text"
        app:textColor="#ff0000"
        app:textSize="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    String text = "Hello\nworld!";
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
         "<html><body style=\"white-space: pre\">"+
         text+
         "</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```